# Change shinydashboard box width

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm quiet new to R but am trying to design a UI which has a main box going across the top of the main body with two smaller boxes underneath. At the moment everything I have tried seems to display it in each corner of the main body. Image attahced. The subsection of my code is below:

```
  dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
          box(plotlyOutput("Map"))),
        fluidRow(
          box(plotlyOutput("Chart")),
          box(tableOutput("Table")))
        )
      )
```

I have tried width and height (100%) etc but now joy.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please choose a descriptive title. “Flexible layout” doesn’t really tell us anything. Even the actual question is still somewhat vague — I had to guess what you actually meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `box` is set to width = 6, so just change that to 12:

> box(..., title = NULL, footer = NULL, status = NULL,   solidHeader =
>   FALSE, background = NULL, width = 6, height = NULL,   collapsible =
>   FALSE, collapsed = FALSE)

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width=12,plotlyOutput("Map"))),
    fluidRow(
      box(plotlyOutput("Chart")),
      box(tableOutput("Table")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Carlos80 [Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) you can find some additional info about the Bootstrap grid system in the `shiny` context.